# Get UTC date and time with time zone offset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL Server function (or composition) to record the UTC date and time *with the timezone offset* into one of my columns of type `datetimeoffset(7)`.

I observe that the [`SYSUTCDATETIME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function gets the UTC date and time into a `datetime2(7)` data type and therefore that doesn't store the offset.

So, my question is: is there a composition of functions that will yield a `datetimeoffset(7)` value with the UTC date time along with the time offset (0:00)?

Comment: You can simply `CONVERT` the value to a `DATETIMEOFFSET`. Alternatively, use `SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` (2016+).